# Flash Player, domain name of webpage it is embedded in?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, web, dns, ip-address

I have developed a flex application (Flex 4.5.1). I want the flex application to be used only by the domain names that I allow. As soon as the application is loaded, I check with the remote database if the domain name is valid.

The problem is that flash player only returns the domain name of the user's machine. What I want is the domain name of the website that the flex application is part of. For instance, if the webpage I browse for my flash application is www.abc.com/index.html, I need www.abc.com or abc.com. Is that possible? Every method I have tried only returns the name of the website visitor's computer.

Thanks

Comment: I spent a lot of time on this sort of problem when creating the watermarking code for flextras components.  Short answr is nothing is solid; and it wasn't worth our trouble.  We eventually gave up on enforcing this sort of thing through a "code" approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no 100% reliable way to get the current url of your swf (I asked this before in the MochiMedia forums: https://www.mochimedia.com/community/forum/topic/reliably-find-the-page-url#d5fe7e47). The main problems:

- You can use `stage.loaderInfo.url`, but that returns the url of the swf, which could be hosted somewhere else (perhaps that could also work). Also if the site uses a custom preloader, then it's probably the url of this preloader rather than your swf.
- You can use `ExternalInterface`, but firstly, Javascript needs to be enabled, and it will break if the site you're using it on embeds your swf using an iframe
- You can use PHP and referral headers, but it'll suffer under the same problem as the js version.

I use something like SecureSWF (http://www.kindi.com) as they have site locking as well as the encryption etc. I couldn't really tell you how it works though, or if it's different from the 3 methods above

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Flash ExternalInterface call to a javaScript function. The javaScript function could return the location

e.g

```
//javascript
function getLocation() {
    return window.location;
}
```

and

```
//AS3
var windowLocation:String=ExternalInterface.call(getLocation) as String;
```

**EDIT**

For those who do not want to do this by Javascript: YOU DO NOT NEED JAVASCRIPT :)

Just send a request to your server from Flash.

Then check the server-side variable corresponding to the http referrer (in ColdFusion, its `CGI.HTTP_REFERRER`. In PHP, its `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`)

This will contain the url of the swf file sending the request.

Comment: For his purposes, this wouldn't help, as the website running the application could forge a fake valid name.

Comment: Thanks Pranav. That is a good answer. But I cannot be 100% sure that I'll get a valid result with that. Like felipemaia said, it is possible to fake the name and  secondly window.location is known to have problems with some browsers that can make my application useless even if the user is browsing from the correct domain.

Comment: Changed my answer, check it out

Comment: Pranav, thanks for the update. But there still exists a problem. Let's say, site abc.com can have the flash player embedded with source set to the one on another site, say, xyz.com. In that case, the flash player is appearing on abc.com while it is actually allowed to work only on xyz.com. The requesting URL would still be that of site xyz.com, wouldn't it? I think 'Application.application.url' returns the url of the requesting swf. But the problem is how to find the domain name of the web page the player is embedded into. Thanks again :)

Comment: In my experiments with this (a few years ago); the JavaScript call will throw an error if the SWF is on a different domain than the enclosing page.  ( Research Cross Site Scripting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting ).  I think there is a property that can be set to allow this sort of access in the way the SWF is embedded in the HTML page, though.